# referenceColumnName alternative in hibernate xml

Tags: java, xml, hibernate

I have two tables

Table1
pk_table1
colx
coly
xyz_fk

Table2
pk_table2
colA
colB
xyz_fk

I need to make a join fetch on xyz_fk column. I figured out that referenceColumnName is the solution for the same using @JoinColumn annotation.

But I didn't find the alternative of the same in hibernate xml using  tag.

Comment: Are you trying to find the xml configuration used to replace the annotation configuration or do you want to mix the two. I'm confused.

Comment: Add your entity files. Lets see what going on there